# Composer require mongodb/mongodb

Tags: raspbian, mongodb

When installing latest MongoDB library, following error is shown

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ composer require mongodb/mongodb
Using version ^1.2 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.2 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.2.0].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I have installed php developer library, installed `pecl` MongoDB dependencies and also updated `php.ini` file.

Steps I have use from the beginning.

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install apache2 php mysql-server phpmyadmin mongodb-server` this step installed MongoDB 2.4. MongoDB 3.x doesn't seem to work with ARM Chipset.
- `sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev` (used this to remove `phpize` error)
- `sudo pecl install mongodb`
- Added `extension=mongodb.so` in `php.ini` file
- `composer require MongoDB/MongoDB`

Comment: Could you [edit] to include the steps you used to install the compiled module for MongoDB and the output of `php -i`? Thanks.

Comment: please take a look @Aurora0001, I have added the details.

Comment: Thank you; could you include the output of `php -i` too?

Comment: It is working now, I don't know why, but first time editing `php.ini` file saved successfully, but not in actual. A reboot made it clear and solved the issue. Thanks :-)

Comment: No problem. Note that we don't encourage adding '[solved]' to your title here; instead, post your solution as an answer below and accept it to show that you resolved the issue. You might also gain some rep for your answer if it helps others!

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the info, I Will update the post soon.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with `php.ini` file, on 1st try, adding `extension=mongodb.so` and saving setting didn't save despite showing the change in the file on opening.

After a reboot of the system, I edited the file again and this time, it worked. I don't know why such thing happened and didn't save but it works fine now.

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Posting a single line of code without any explanation does not constitute as an answer. Since you are new to the site you should take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how things work around here. You might find this section [How do I write a good answer?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) In the [help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/) useful as well.